# Formula based on Option in opencart

Tags: php, formula, opencart2.x

I am new to using opencart (2.1.0.2) and I am wanting to put in a custom formula on each product based on if they select the only checkbox (which created through options) http://cms-test2.dynamic-stationery.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=64_65&product_id=63

So the formula would be setup fee ($121) x quantity ordered @ $0.88 + $20
  e.g for 50 books = 121 + (50 x .88) + 20 = $185 + the total of the actual books, so complete total would be 892.85

hopefully this makes sense

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart has a functionality for modules that calculate total. You can duplicate one of exists modules, rewrite it and configure in admin panel. But don`t forgot about sort order of this modules b/c they get total value from previous total module as base for calculation.